# How can I simplify my current ARM Machine Assembly better (from a c code that checks for any of various sets of bits all being set)?

Tags: c, assembly, optimization, arm, simplify

I started with this code:

```
char player_won_c(player_t * player){
  char won = 0;
  if      ((player->state & 0x0007) == 0x0007) won = 1;
  else if ((player->state & 0x0070) == 0x0070) won = 1;
  else if ((player->state & 0x0700) == 0x0700) won = 1;
  else if ((player->state & 0x0111) == 0x0111) won = 1;
  else if ((player->state & 0x0222) == 0x0222) won = 1;
  else if ((player->state & 0x0444) == 0x0444) won = 1;
  else if ((player->state & 0x0124) == 0x0124) won = 1;
  else if ((player->state & 0x0421) == 0x0421) won = 1;
  return won;
}
```

And for reference it's a tictactoe game with the following kind of determinations of players locations:
[Player State Explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZkHT.jpg)

And and trying to write it more simply in ARM Machine Assembly (using Keil uVision5). Here is what I have and just trying to write it more simply?

```
 //char won = 0; 
    MOVS          r0,#0x00
 //if      ((player->state & 0x0007) == 0x0007) won = 1; 
    LDRB          r2,[r1,#0x00]
    AND           r2,r2,#0x07
    CMP           r2,#0x07
    BNE           0x08000C12
    MOVS          r0,#0x01
    B             0x08000C7E
//else if ((player->state & 0x0070) == 0x0070) won = 1; 
    LDRB          r2,[r1,#0x00]
    AND           r2,r2,#0x70
    CMP           r2,#0x70
    BNE           0x08000C20
    MOVS          r0,#0x01
    B             0x08000C7E
//else if ((player->state & 0x0700) == 0x0700) won = 1; 
    LDRH          r2,[r1,#0x00]
    AND           r2,r2,#0x700
    CMP           r2,#0x700
    BNE           0x08000C30
    MOVS          r0,#0x01
    B             0x08000C7E
//else if ((player->state & 0x0111) == 0x0111) won = 1; 
    LDRH          r2,[r1,#0x00]
    MOVW          r3,#0x111
    ANDS          r2,r2,r3
    CMP           r2,r3
    BNE           0x08000C40
    MOVS          r0,#0x01
    B             0x08000C7E
//else if ((player->state & 0x0222) == 0x0222) won = 1; 
    LDRH          r2,[r1,#0x00]
    MOVW          r3,#0x222
    ANDS          r2,r2,r3
    CMP           r2,r3
    BNE           0x08000C50
    MOVS          r0,#0x01
    B             0x08000C7E
//else if ((player->state & 0x0444) == 0x0444) won = 1; 
    LDRH          r2,[r1,#0x00]
    MOVW          r3,#0x444
    ANDS          r2,r2,r3
    CMP           r2,r3
    BNE           0x08000C60
    MOVS          r0,#0x01
    B             0x08000C7E
//else if ((player->state & 0x0124) == 0x0124) won = 1; 
    LDRH          r2,[r1,#0x00]
    AND           r2,r2,#0x124
    CMP           r2,#0x124
    BNE           0x08000C70
    MOVS          r0,#0x01
    B             0x08000C7E
//else if ((player->state & 0x0421) == 0x0421) won = 1; 
//return won; 
    LDRH          r2,[r1,#0x00]
    MOVW          r3,#0x421
    ANDS          r2,r2,r3
    CMP           r2,r3
    BNE           0x08000C7E
    MOVS          r0,#0x01
```

Any suggestions to write more simple? I think my functions are a little too complex and want to try to have a more "basic" approach to be able to teach it to my sister.

Comment: Have you tried looking at optimized C compiler output?  Any decent compiler will load once and apply various check, not compiling each else if into a fully separate block of asm.  e.g. clang optimizing for an ARMv8 CPU (so `movw` is available for 16-bit constants): https://godbolt.org/z/7K1G1YqMv

Comment: Although some of those optimizations to save instructions make it more efficient but not *simpler*, and it doesn't notice that it could right-shift and reuse a `0x111` bitmask.  If you want simple, looping over an array of bitmasks would make the code nice and compact.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the assembler by caching `player->state` and jumping to the common code, which sets `win=1` like

```
LDRH          r2,[r1,#0x00];   // state = player->state
AND           r0,r2,#0x07      // use another register, e.g. r3 or r0
CMP           r0,#0x07
BEQ           win
AND           r0,r2,#0x70      // Now r2 is still intact
CMP           r0,#0x70
BEQ           win
```

Anything more will probably make the code more complex, but possible smaller. The only transformation/regularity I was able to spot is that the first three conditions can be evaluated in parallel, by some advanced bit-hackery: `if ((state + 0x111) & 0x888) goto win`.

Looping over the 8 possible patterns can move some of the complexity from code to data. This version adds a *sentinel* or terminating value of zero at the end of the constants we need to compare. We don't even need to compare that the loaded constant is zero, as it can be done afterwards, after the the loop condition of `(state & 0) == 0` is necessary true.

```
 LDRH r2, [r1];        // cache state
 LDR  r0, .table_addr  // load the address of constant table
 loop:
 LDRH r0, [r3], #02;   // load the constant to compare with, post increment
 AND  r4, r2, r0
 CMP  r4, r0
 BNE  loop
 CMP  r0, #0           // return 0 iff the constant we loaded was 0
 MOVNE r0, #1          // otherwise we have a win, i.e. return 1 (in r0)


 .table_addr:
    .long _table_data
 _table_data:
    .short 0x7, 0x70, 0x700, 0x111, 0x222, 0x444, 0x124, 0x421, 0
```

Comment: Oh interesting, yeah a tic-tac-toe bitboard that only normally uses the low 3 bits in each nibble leaves room for producing carry into bits that you know won't be set in the input.  That check for `0x888` can't work in the fully general case for arbitrary `int` or `short` inputs, e.g. it would false positive for `0x8`, but it's great for this bitboard format.

Comment: Commenting my self, I picked up the table address loading from godbolt, and was wondering, if it could be done without the indirection.

Comment: Compilers will put the pointer in a literal pool near code (between functions), and the table itself in `.rodata` (assuming it's `const`).  If you put the whole table nearby, you can just reference it relative to `PC`, e.g. making that `ldr r0, .table_addr` into an ADD to PC or whatever is a good way to do that on whatever ARM version.  (A PC-relative addr mode in the loop wouldn't be any better whether it's possible or not; in that case you'd need to init an index register to 0.)  In a small program, probably anywhere in `.rodata` is close enough to reference directly.

Comment: Possibly `add r3, pc, offset_to_table` would do it. `Movk r3, table_high, #16; Orr r3, table_low` would not work without support of linker/object file format that would be able to split relocation offsets to low and high.